# Aurelia: main.js, app.js and app.html still requested despite bundle

Tags: aurelia

In my running Aurelia app, I have successfully created a bundle to load all my scripts from. These scripts reside in a folder, namely /Scripts/app/views, where you can find also my main.js, app.js and app.html.

After I create the bundle, if I check the config.js file at the root of my app I see that my bundle contains those 3 files.

Yet, when I reload the app, the browser loads correctly the bundle instead of every single file, but still, there are also 3 single http requests to those 3 files. Why is that and how can I remove those calls? Does it have something to do with the fact that they are the "entry point" of the app?

Further info:

- I use JSPM
- I did not use the skeleton, I just installed the aurelia framework and other components with JSPM and NPM, and then ported my old app on top of it
- For bundling I use the aurelia-bundler node module with gulp: see gulpfile below

```
    var gulp = require('gulp'),
    bundler = require('aurelia-bundler'),
    uglify = require('gulp-uglify'),
    htmlmin = require('gulp-htmlmin'),    
    del = require('del');

    var config = {
        compact: true,
        force: true,
        baseURL: '.',                   // baseURL of the application
        configPath: './config.js',      // config.js file. Must be within `baseURL`
        bundles: {
            "Scripts/build/app-build": {           // bundle name/path. Must be within `baseURL`. Final path is: `baseURL/dist/app-build.js`.
                includes: [                
                  '[Scripts/app/**/*.js]',
                  'Scripts/app/**/*.html!text',
                  'Content/*.css!text'
                ],            
                options: {
                    compact: true,
                    inject: true,
                    minify: true,
                    rev: true,
                    force: true,
                }
            },
            "Scripts/build/vendor-build": {
                includes: [
                    'jspm_packages/npm/babel-runtime@5.8.38/helpers/class-call-check.js',
                    'jspm_packages/npm/babel-runtime@5.8.38/helpers/create-class.js',
                    'jspm_packages/npm/babel-runtime@5.8.38/core-js/object/define-property.js',
                    'jspm_packages/npm/core-js@1.2.7/library/fn/object/define-property.js',
                    'jspm_packages/npm/babel-runtime@5.8.38/core-js/object/define-properties.js',
                    'jspm_packages/npm/core-js@1.2.7/library/fn/object/define-properties.js',
                    'npm:aurelia-framework@1.0.7',
                    'npm:aurelia-loader-default@1.0.0',
                    'npm:aurelia-logging-console@1.0.0',
                    'npm:aurelia-templating-binding@1.0.0',
                    'npm:aurelia-templating-resources@1.1.1',
                    'npm:aurelia-templating-router@1.0.0',
                    'npm:aurelia-knockout@1.0.2',
                    'npm:aurelia-history-browser@1.0.0',
                    'npm:aurelia-bootstrapper@1.0.0',
                    'npm:aurelia-fetch-client@1.0.1',
                    'npm:aurelia-router@1.0.6',
                    'npm:aurelia-animator-css@1.0.1',
                    'npm:babel-core@5.8.38',
                    'npm:babel-runtime@5.8.38',
                    'npm:core-js@1.2.7',
                    'github:systemjs/plugin-text@0.0.9'
                ],
                options: {
                    compact: true,
                    inject: true,
                    minify: true,
                    rev: true,
                    force: true,
                }
            }
        }
    };

    gulp.task('clean', function () {
        return del.sync(['Scripts/build/**', '!Scripts/build']);    
    });

    gulp.task('uglify', ['clean'], function () { 
        return gulp.src(['Scripts/accounts/i18n.js', 'Scripts/lib/i18n_error.js'])
          .pipe(uglify())
          .pipe(gulp.dest('Scripts/build'));
    });

    gulp.task('minify', ['uglify'], function () {
        return gulp.src(['Scripts/app/views/error.html', 'templates/_head.html', 'templates/_contactSupportPanel.html'])
          .pipe(htmlmin({ collapseWhitespace: true }))
          .pipe(gulp.dest('Scripts/build'))
    });

    gulp.task('build', ['minify'], function () {
        return bundler.bundle(config);
    });
```

Comment: Based on the fact that you mention a `config.js` file, I'll assume you are using the skeleton project to get started and are using jspm? You need to add a lot more details if you want help. What did you do to get started, how did you bundle, etc.

Comment: sorry, this was part of a longer question which can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40236981/aurelia-bundler-does-not-delete-references-to-old-versioned-bundles, where I got the advice to split it into multiple questions.